# Monitor application log files with variable names with rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I have an application on linux that puts randomly (truly randomly, not following any pattern) named log files in `/opt/application/logs`.

I need to read all these files with rsyslog and forward their content to a central rsyslog server.

The forwarding part is easy but how could I push these logs to the local rsyslog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
xtail /opt/application/logs |logger
```